# Invalid Host Header when using elasticsearch client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

When using the elasticsearch client (from the elasticsearch npm version 15.4.1), the AWS elasticsearch service complains about an Invalid Host Header. This happens for every request even though they work.

I double-checked the configuration for initializing the elasticsearch client and the parameter "host" is correctly formed.

```
let test = require('elasticsearch').Client({
    host: 'search-xxx.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com',
    connectionClass: require('http-aws-es')
});
```

I expected to get a clean ElasticsearchRequest without a corresponding InvalidHostHeaderRequests (I can see these logs on the Cluster health dashboard of the Amazon Elasticsearch Service).

Comment: maybe it is:     `hosts: ['search-xxx.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com']`

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan, I've tried straight away and it's not working. Still trying other solutions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the problem.
When using elasticsearch library to connect to an AWS ES cluster, the previous syntax can lead to problems, so the best way to initialize the client is specifying the entire 'host' object as follows:

```
host: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'search-xxx.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com',
    port: '443',
    path: '/'
```

The problem here is that probably AWS ES Cluster expects the host field inside the host object and this leads to the "Invalid Host Header" issue. Hope this will help the community to write better code.
Refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/16.x/host-reference.html for reference.

Comment: I have checked the network packets with wireshark that is being sent to Elasticsearch using both notations you have mentioned. I saw that the Host header is there for both requests, they are identical. Did you resolve your problem by only applying this or are there any other changes you have made?

Comment: As far as I can remember, there are no other changes I made to it in order to make it works.